# ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework - throws errors

Tags: bundling-and-minification, web-optimization, microsoft-ajax-minifier

ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework throws errors in CSS minification, I tried, validated and did everything to fix, but seems framework bug

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(1,1-2): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: .
(2,14-15): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';': :
(2,15-19): run-time error JS1306: Invalid numeric literal: 12px
 */
.a {
    font-size:12px;
}
;
```

This was just a single line test to see if it still works but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Sorry issue was with the bundle tutorial from where I just copied, its fixed. THanks

Comment: Can you please tell me how you got it fixed because I am also into the same thing and got stuck for a whole day

Comment: I bet he used created a ScriptBundle with css files instead of a StyleBundle -- at least, that's what I did and got the same errors :)